# Do Dictionary.Keys.ToArray() and Dictionary.Values.ToArray() preserve ordering?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a dictionary of city-population objects:

```
var cityPopulation = new new Dictionary<string, int>()
                    {
                        ["Sacramento"] = 495234,
                        ["Miami"] = 453579,
                        ["Memphis"] = 652717
                    });
```

I need to get 2 corresponding (same order) arrays. Can I be sure that when I do

```
var cities = cityPopulation.Keys.ToArray();
var populations = cityPopulation.Values.ToArray();
```

Order of both arrays will be preserved - i.e.:

cities - 1st element will be Sacramento, 2nd - Miami and 3rd - Memphis, and for array of populations - 1st - 495234, 2nd - 453579 and 3rd - 652717 correspondingly (array of cities should correspond to the array of populations).

How can I be sure about this, and if not - how do I preserve the order of those arrays?

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn’t keep items in order. Do you need to keep items in order, or do you just need to make sure that `cities` and `populations` have corresponding elements at the same indexes?

Comment: `ToArray` will surely preserve the order, however a dictionary doesn´t have any, as it´s just a hash-based collection.

Comment: @Ryan - I need to have corresponding elements at the same indexes (not the order)

Answer (score 5):

No. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not preserve ordering.

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.
>
> *From [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN*

For `Keys` and `Value` properties documentation says their order is not specified, but it's consistent between the two:

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` returned by the `Keys` property.
>
> *From [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN*

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't "preserve order." Or, to be more precise, they do preserve order, but a dictionary isn't ordered to begin with.

That being said, it looks like your ***actual*** requirement is to produce two arrays that contain the items found in the dictionary and also correlate with one another. Such an arrangement is known as [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array).

To make this happen, you just need to create an enumeration that is sorted deterministically (doesn't matter by what, but the key is a pretty obvious candidate, since it is guaranteed to be unique). Once you have a sorted list, just select the keys and values into their own arrays.

```
var sortedPopulation = cityPopulation.OrderBy( a => a.Key );
string[] cities = sortedPopulation.Select( a => a.Key ).ToArray();
int[] populations = sortedPopulation.Select( a => a.Value ).ToArray();
```

This should give you the two arrays you need, with elements aligned, even if they are not in the "original sort order" (which technically doesn't even exist).

Full example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var cityPopulation = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"Sacramento",495234 },
        {"Miami",     453579 },
        {"Memphis",   652717 }
    };

    var sortedPopulation = cityPopulation.OrderBy( a => a.Key );
    string[] cities = sortedPopulation.Select( a => a.Key ).ToArray();
    int[] populations = sortedPopulation.Select( a => a.Value ).ToArray();

    foreach (var c in cities)
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    foreach (var p in populations)
        Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Output:

```
Memphis
Miami
Sacramento
652717
453579
495234
```

If for some reason you would like to get the results without sorting and without enumerating the original list twice, you could also do something like this:

```
public static void SplitDictionary<T1, T2>(Dictionary<T1, T2> input, out T1[] keys, out T2[] values)
{
    keys = new T1[input.Count];
    values = new T2[input.Count];
    int i = 0;

    foreach ( var entry in input )
    {
        keys[i] = entry.Key;
        values[i++] = entry.Value;
    }
}
```

This works because, even though the dictionary can't be relied on for its order, we retrieve the key and value at the same time. Once they are retrieved and put into an array, their order is fixed.

[See my code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TuwDC)

Comment: If you downvoted, please also comment so I can improve the answer.

Comment: When you do `sortedPopulation.Select(...).ToArray()` two times you will get a warning - "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable".

Comment: No you don't. Sounds like you have Resharper. VS doesn't care and there is absolutely nothing wrong with iterating twice over the same enumeration. But for completeness I have added another code example that avoids the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is non-deterministic. There is no implicit ordering of hashtables. In short do not rely on the order being the same as when you added the values.

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

[You can read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)